# Domain not loading on 1and1 bitnami wordpress application on cloud server?

Tags: centos, apache-2.4, wordpress, bitnami

if you check following domain:

top-produkttest.de

You will see, that nothing is loading. The Domain is pointed to the servers' IP Adress and I configured the domain in the vhosts file. The server is running on CentOS 7 and bitnami was preinstalled. Apache2 is running. I also can't access it via the Servers' IP Adress. I have another ubuntu server and I am positive, that the vhosts is configured correctly. Apache2 is not giving back any error messages at all.

Instead of trying to start wordpress, I just put an "index.html" into the directory, so I think somehow it doesn't resolve all of my settings, but I don't know where to look. All bitnami modules are running (through the /opt/bitnami/... start command)

I really don't know how to debug that problem. When I ping the website, it says "x packages send, but 0 received. 100% data loss".

Does anyone know, what could be the problem here and where I can start? I searched through the whole bitnami config, but the only thing it tells, is how to setup the vhosts(which I did).

Edit after comment:

I checked that answer and both are not correct for me.

When I check Port 80 it says:

```
sudo netstat -tnlp | grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      31320/httpd.bin
```

And for the firewall part I checked with: `nmap -sT -O localhost`

And got back:

```
PORT     STATE SERVICE
21/tcp   open  ftp
22/tcp   open  ssh
25/tcp   open  smtp
80/tcp   open  http
443/tcp  open  https
3306/tcp open  mysql
```

Edit2:

My iptables config:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Comment: The timeout points to a firewall problem. You can't check the firewall with tests to localhost, the local interface is usually not routed through the firewall. You have to check this from outside your server.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider how could I check this outside from my server? I just see, that I can't access it

Comment: @FrederikWitte run the nmap comman on a different machine than your server that should be able to reach it. You can also run `iptables -L` to check the servers local firewall, but even when that doesn't show anything it's still possible that there is a hardware firewall in front of your server.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I posted my iptables config now. Can you see anything of any interest there?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your server is running into performance issues. I reckon it's just being extremely slow for any reason. In order to identify your problem, I recommend  you the following actions:

- Check the list of processes consuming CPU and memory. You can do it by logging in to your machine console via SSH and execute the following commands:

  ```
  ps -e -orss=,args= | sort -b -k1,1n | pr -TW$COLUMNS
  ps -e -o pcpu,nice,state,cputime,args --sort -pcpu | head -10
  ```
- In case of problems with the disk size, check the free disk space and which directories have a large number of files:

  ```
  df -ih
  df -h
  cd /opt/bitnami
  sudo find . -type f | cut -d "/" -f 2 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
  du -h -d 1
  ```
- Block Suspicious IP Addresses. To obtain a list of IP addresses sending requests to your server, run the command below:

  ```
  tail -n 10000 /opt/bitnami/apache2/logs/access_log | awk '{print $1}'| sort| uniq -c| sort -nr| head -n 10
  ```
- Once the list of addresses has been generated, check their activity with the following command. Substitute the IP-ADDRESS placeholder with each of the IP addresses from the list.

  ```
  cat access_log | grep IP-ADDRESS
  ```
- If an IP address is not a known internal or external IP address and its behaviour is suspicious (for example, accessing only one page or attempting to log in multiple times), it could be a bot. 
  Block a suspicious IP address using the iptables command. 
  Substitute the IP-ADDRESS placeholder with the IP address you wish to block:

  ```
  sudo su
  iptables -A INPUT -s IP-ADDRESS -j DROP
  ```

NOTE: Use this with caution. If you don't specify an IP address, you will block yourself. To delete a rule, execute these commands. Substitute the IP-ADDRESS placeholder with the IP address you wish to allow:

```
sudo su
iptables -D INPUT -s IP-ADDRESS -j DROP
```

- To have a rule active when the machine reboots, define the rule and then follow these steps:

  - Execute the following commands:

    ```
    sudo su
    iptables-save > /opt/bitnami/iptables-rules
    crontab -e
    ```
  - Edit the crontab file and include this line at the end of the file:

    ```
    @reboot /sbin/iptables-restore < /opt/bitnami/iptables-rules
    ```
  - Save the file and exit. This way, on every boot, the system will load the iptables rules and apply them.

I hope this information is useful for you.

Comment: I have a cloud panel and the CPU and RAM are used max 25% at any given time.